# Application Publishing for Flutter with VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am pretty new to flutter and VS Code and I have never actually tried to publish anything with it. I am trying to make the equivalent of a .exe for mobile apps. I am not exactly sure how to achieve that in VS Code and there may be different ways I have to do it based on if I am making the IOS or Android download. Any tips? I cannot seem to find the right thing to google when it comes to it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a terminal window and run following command to generate android build.

> You'll have to sign the `APK` to generate release build. Google `how to sign apk` and you'll be good to go.

```sh
flutter build apk --release
```

For releasing IOS app, the process is much more complicated. You can use this [guide](https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-release-your-flutter-app-for-ios-and-android/).